# Find the 1000th digit of $N=61218243036\ldots$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

If all the multiples of 6 are written side-by-side, then a large integer $N$ is generated as follows:

$$N=61218243036\ldots$$

The question is to find the $1000$th digit of $N$. Please simply give a hint as to how I can proceed. I have calculated the answer through brute force counting (with the help of a computer) but I am looking for something more elegant.

Comment: It depends on how sophisticated a method you are interested in. One way to proceed could be to "count" the number of multiples of $6$ of a given digit length. Here are some hints. There are $\lfloor 10/6 \rfloor$ multiples of $6$ with $1$ digit. There are $\lfloor 100/6 \rfloor - \lfloor 10/6 \rfloor$ multiples of $6$ with $2$ digits. There are $\lfloor 1000/6 \rfloor - \lfloor 100/6 \rfloor$ multiples of $6$ with $3$ digits, and so on. See if you can use this information to get to an answer. If not, I'm happy to post more.

Comment: Thanks! I got the answer quickly enough through this method. But you have piqued my curiosity...what other methods are there to solve this problem.

Answer (score 3):

There are $10^{k}-10^{k-1}=3(3 \times 10^{k-1})=6 (15 \times 10^{k-2})$ numbers with $k$ digits. Therefore, for $k \geq 2$, there are $15 \times 10^{k-2}$ multiples of $6$ with $k$ digits.

So the bit of $N$ that uses all the multiples of $6$ with at most $m$ digits will have length $1 + \sum_{k=2}^m k(15 \times 10^{k-2})=1 + 15(\sum_{k=0}^{m-2} (k+2) 10^k)$, which, [after some algebra](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=1%20%2b%2015%20%2a%20sum%20%28k%2b2%29%2010%5Ek%20for%20k%20from%200%20to%20m-2), is equal to $\frac{10^m(9m-1) - 26}{54}$.

Now, you can explicitly find the largest $m$ such that this expression is less than $1000$, and work from there...

Comment: And the solution for $m$ is explicitly given by Lambert $$m < \frac{W\left(\frac{27013\ 2^{8/9} \log (10)}{9 \sqrt[9]{5}}\right)}{\log
   (10)}+\frac{1}{9} \simeq 3.27776$$

Answer (score 2):

There is only 1 multiple of 6 with one digit. 
There are [100/6 - 1] = 15 multiples of 6 with two digits: then 30 digits. 
There are [1000/6 - 15 - 1] = 150 multiples of 6 with three digits: then 450 digits.

At this point, we have counted the first 1 + 30 + 450 = 481 digits of N. There remain other 1000 - 481 = 519 digits. The first 516 of these are included in the next 516/4 = 129 multiples of 6, which have all four digits.

Thus, we have counted a total of 1 + 15 + 150 + 129 = 295 multiples of 6, and there remains three digits to arrive to the 1000th digit of N. Thus, the 1000th digit of N is the third digit of the 296° multiple of 6. Since 296 * 6 = 1776, the digit is 7.

Comment: I would have stopped after the first paragraph as OP asked for a hint only.  It is a good one.  The rest is correct, but specifically unrequested.